# Multiple AND relationship in Wordpress Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to make a query that has multiple AND relationship requirements. So I have courses and I need the query to look at the custom fields and find the courses (custom posts) between 2 dates, at a location at if the course is open. This is the code I have any idea why it is returning nothing when I have a course that should fulfil the requirements of the query.

```
      $query = array(
            'post_type' => 'courses',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'course_date',
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'value' => '2017-01-01',
                            'type' => 'DATE'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'course_date',
                            'compare' => '<=',
                            'value' => '2017-12-30',
                            'type' => 'DATE'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'course_location',
                            'compare' => '=',
                            'value' => 'Leeds',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'course_open',
                            'compare' => '=',
                            'value' => false,
                        ),
                ),
        );
```

I think it is the way I have structured the query which is not correct. Basically all the criteria needs to be met.

Comment: try to remove the `course_open` array and check. also you store the dates in this format in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your query looks pretty well done. It says:

> *Give me all courses, between 2017-01-01 and 2017-12-30 where the course location is Leeds and the course is not open.*

Are you sure you have courses like this in your database?

Why your query might fail anyway:

1. Have you tried without type DATE? (Though this should be correct)
2. course_open value: Have you tried to use the exact string value instead of `false`?

If it STILL does not work remove single parts of the query to find out which one may be responsible for no results to be returned.

You also can check the generated SQL manually f.e. like this:

```
$posts = new WP_Query($query);
echo "Last SQL-Query: {$posts->request}";
```

Comment: Got it to work. Its how I was storing custom fields for open or closed. I was storing it as true and false but it was a string obviously /facepalm. Any idea how I store TRUE and False?

Comment: Well youvcan not save boolean values in the meta table directly. Usually I store 1 for true and 0 for false and do intval. Alternativley an empty value for false. Or you store trie and false as strings, but you always have to apply boolval then.